# c++ strange Segmentation fault appears

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, undefined-behavior

## Description

`SFDD` and `Manager` are classes that I created myself, following is my test file for testing class SFDD. (You can skip them and check the my test results)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "SFDD.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    vector<int> vars_order;
    int var_no = 18;
    for (int i = 1; i <= var_no; ++i) vars_order.push_back(i);

    Vtree* v = new Vtree(1, var_no*2-1, vars_order);
    v->save_file_as_dot("vtree");
    Manager m(v);

    SFDD sfdd1 = m.sfddZero();  // create a SFDD representing Zero
    SFDD sfdd2 = m.sfddOne();
    SFDD sfdd3 = m.sfddVar(3);
    SFDD sfdd4 = m.sfddVar(11);

    SFDD sfdd6 = sfdd3.And(sfdd4, m, true);
    sfdd6.save_file_as_dot("f=x11_and_x3");  // export sfdd6
    
    cout << "Haha 1" << endl;  // flag 1: for debugging

    SFDD sfdd8 = sfdd4.Xor(sfdd6, m, true);
    sfdd8.save_file_as_dot("f=x11_xor_(x11_and_x3)");

    cout << "Haha 2" << endl;  // flag 2: for debugging
    sfdd3.Xor(sfdd8, m, true).save_file_as_dot("f=x3_xor_x11_xor_(x11_and_x3)");

    cout << "Haha 3" << endl;  // flag 3: for debugging

    return 0;
}
```

After `make` and run. I got

```
Haha 1
Haha 2
Haha 3
```

which means it works. (execute to the end)

#### 1. Segmentation fault 1

After I comment this line

```
sfdd6.save_file_as_dot("f=x11_and_x3");  // export sfdd6
```

I `make` and run again, I got

```
Haha 1
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

This comfuses me, because the function `save_file_as_dot(string s)` is just to export class SFDD to a `dot` file (dot is a language drawing simple graphs), I think it shouldn't be able to avoid a segmentation fault.

#### 2. Segmentation fault 2

After I comment this line (uncomment above line this time)

```
SFDD sfdd1 = m.sfddZero();  // create a SFDD
```

I got

```
Haha 1
Haha 2
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

This comfuses me again, because last several lines don't use object `sfdd1`, why commenting this line avoids sementation fault?

Why do these segmentation faults appear? All I need are some clues or directions to solve these. Thank you.

Comment: "*which means it works*", you are clearly not familiar with **undefined behavior**.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Also I wouldn't trust the code at the link, it has a terrible style and even though it's subjective, bad style means bad taste, and bad taste means bad quality.

Comment: You try to open the file "dotG/test0/f=x11_and_x3.dot", but you never check whether it was created. `f.open()` will not create the subdirectories for you, and the equals sign in the file name may be valid, but it's suspiocious. The second seggie might occur in the call to `sfdd8.save_file_as_dot()`.

Comment: Sorry for my confusing question. "it works" means I run "./test0" many times, segmentation faults never appear, and I check the output dot file, they are all right as I wish. So I just think my program works. So second one is the most confusing thing for me, why commenting an uncorrelated object cause a seg fault.

Comment: @BaummitAugen I will complete my question later. The whole code is very complex, but I will try. Thanks for your advice and useful link. Learning...

Comment: I admit that the code looks bad now, could you give me some advice to improve it?

Comment: @MOehm Thanks for your help. The code is messy now, I will try your advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be aware of the concept of *[Undefined Behavior](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub)*, in your circumstances it's pretty safe to assume that your code invokes such behavior at some point and it sometimes causes the program to abruptly terminate due to a segmentation fault and sometimes it just doesn't.

To solve this problem, you need a tool like *[valgrind](http://valgrind.org)*. Using this tool or it's equivalent for your OS and environment, you should be able to find the exact place where the violation occurs and solve the apparently random segmentation fault that appears and disappears depending on parts of the code that do not have any relation to the real problem.

Comment: It also might be worth adding ``-g`` flag (both Clang & GCC have this flag and it means the same when using them) to the compilation process to expose debugging symbols (and line numbers for valgrind's messages).

Comment: @mdziekon Assuming the OP will read the documentation for *valgrind* then this will be explained in it. But it's also a good idea to mention here, so thanks for your comment.

Comment: Valgrind is really useful, I comment all my test code except creating only one object of my class, still detect leaked memory. I know it's might caused by the constructor or destructor of the class that I defined.